# Proguard rules to keep public static method name unchanged in AAR library

Tags: android, android-proguard

How to keep static method name unchanged and obfuscate everything inside the method.

Example code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void MyFunc(Conetext context, String str, int i) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Hello world "+ str + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here I want to keep `MyFunc` unchanged.

**Amit Vaghela** why are you doing this? If you don't understand what I asked please ignore my post.

Do you think `-keepclassmembernames` will obfuscate entire code inside the `MyFunc`? I tested:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-keep,allowobfuscation class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    public static void * (...);
}
```

And it didn't work and that's why I am here to ask. If you cannot help you better ignore it.

Comment: Answer is a reference. @MortyChoi, will `-keepclassmembernames` obfuscate everything inside the function?